# App map route link navigates in chrome but not in google maps app

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, navigation

My app provides maps and route maps for users to click on.  The route maps are step-by-step directions (like trail or bike route) and the link is opened in the browser (chrome/safari) the step by step navigation works fine.  But when the same link is opened in Google Maps App it only shows preview and there is no option to navigate the route.

Here is a sample route:  `https://goo.gl/maps/si1wWkqBj5D9dErXA`

The link gets translated to this:  `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/27.9372535,-82.4768151/27.9370622,-82.4769956/27.9332062,-82.4687084/27.9370453,-82.4768353/@27.9329297,-82.4782615,16z/data=!4m26!4m25!1m0!1m15!3m4!1m2!1d-82.4768731!2d27.9336904!3s0x88c2c361bec618a7:0x3f6da8d9bad436ab!3m4!1m2!1d-82.46967!2d27.9353733!3s0x88c2c4994d9e4bf5:0x86dffeca64f91ea8!3m4!1m2!1d-82.4696651!2d27.9372217!3s0x88c2c49bf6f34cbd:0x68357d91d69adf7f!1m5!3m4!1m2!1d-82.4817505!2d27.9267562!3s0x88c2c35c3b916041:0xb991d57b84a48ebe!1m0!3e2?hl=en`

The route was created on google.com/maps - add all your next stop locations, then underneath that send yourself the route link.

*Note: Location/GPS is turned on already...and maps has permission to use GPS.  So its not a gps/permissions issue.*

1. Whats wrong with the link that it works in Chrome but not in
   Maps?  Can the link be fixed to get it to work in Maps app?
2. Is there a way to force specific links to open in the system browser -
   and not ask to open in Maps?

Unless I can figure out or resolve this issue in Maps app, I will need to force the user to the browser - but if I can't force that, then the problem is the user has chosen to use Maps causing even yet another problem because the user will never be prompted again.

Comment: I'm currently using these methods and everything goes well:

    directionUsingGoogleMap () {
      const url = `http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=${this.locationToDirect[1]},${this.locationToDirect[0]}&mode=d`
      openURL(url)
    },
    directionUsingWaze () {
      const url = `https://waze.com/ul?ll=${this.locationToDirect[1]},${this.locationToDirect[0]}&navigate=yes`
      openURL(url)
    },

Comment: @Mr. - Does navigation, for both links, work in google chrome and google maps?  Again, my issue is getting the navigation to work in the maps app.

Comment: In the mobile version, it opens Maps, and in the browser (SPA) navigate to map.google.com.

Comment: @Mr. - your links look like destination address/lat-lng are provided, implying the start point is the users current location and they need navigate to the provided location.  Mine are step-by-step route maps - that provide a starting Point A...and end at Point F.   Chrome navigates the step-by-step just fine, but only displays a preview in Maps - no ability to navigate, and thats what I am trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.

If the user opens the step-by-step route in Maps (app) and the user is too far away from the actual starting point, navigation is not offered.  Sort of makes sense, your device can't navigate a route you are not near.  But if the user is at or very near the starting point, Maps app then offers navigation.

Testing the route from a remote location, where your actual GPS location is to far way from the starting point, then it only shows you the option to "preview" the route.